# Toolbar items dissapear when view changed with UIActionSheet

Tags: ios, ios6, uitoolbar, uiactionsheet, viewwillappear

When initiating a view from a `UIActionSheet` button, upon returning to the view via the navigationBar back button, the toolbar while still visible does not have any of the buttons that were previously on it. This error has arisen since updating to iOS 6 and occurs while testing it on the simulator and a device running iOS 6 only. If I comment out the code that hides the toolbar on the view pushed by the `UIActionSheet` the buttons are added when going back.

I'm making my toolbar items programatically in `viewWillAppear` and showing the `UIActionSheet` from the toolbar which I'm accessing via `self.navigationController.toolbar`.

Any idea what is causing this problem? It's only happened since iOS 6 has come around so is there any changes that I need to take into account regarding `viewWillAppear`?

This is how the view is pushed from the actionSheet:

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    if (actionSheet.tag == 2) {

    if (buttonIndex == 0) {

        [self dismissAllTips];

        self.actionNoteAddView= [[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"IDActionNoteAddView"] retain];

        actionNoteAddView.note_id = 0;
        actionNoteAddView.iscompleted=0;

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"tool_tips"];

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:actionNoteAddView animated:TRUE];

        [actionNoteAddView release];

    }else if(buttonIndex == 1){

        ...
```

These are the view methods for the pushed view:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = NO;
    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES];

    txtcontent.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;

}


-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

}
```

These are the view methods for the view that pushed the view using the actionSheet:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO];
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=NO;

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.8 green:0.45 blue:0.2 alpha:1];
    self.navigationController.toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    self.navigationController.toolbar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.8 green:0.45 blue:0.2 alpha:1]; 

    UIImage *actionButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"31-circle-plus@2x.png"];
    UIBarButtonItem *actionButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:actionButtonImage style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(actionPressed:)
                                     ];

    UIImage *dashButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"19-gear.png"];
    UIBarButtonItem *dashButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:dashButtonImage style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(settingsPressed:)];




    UIBarButtonItem *flexItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                                                              target:nil
                                                                              action:nil];

    NSArray *toolitems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:dashButton, flexItem, actionButton, flexItem, nil];

    [self setToolbarItems:toolitems];

    self.title = @"Dashboard";

    defaultProfile.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"default_profile"];

    BOOL dailyProcess = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"daily_process"];

    if(dailyProcess){

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"daily_process"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

        loading = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

        labelProcess = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 105, 240, 30)];
        labelProcess.text = @"Processing...";
        labelProcess.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        labelProcess.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.8 green:0.45 blue:0.2 alpha:1];
        [labelProcess setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20]];

        loading.opaque = NO;
        loading.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0f alpha:0.6f];

        indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
        [indicator setHidesWhenStopped:YES];
        indicator.center = self.view.center;

        [self.view addSubview:loading];
        [self.view addSubview:indicator];

        [self.view addSubview:labelProcess];

        [indicator startAnimating];

    }

}


-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(157, 365, 10, 10);
    UIView *viewToPointAt = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

    [self.view addSubview:viewToPointAt];

    BOOL willies = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"tool_tips"];

    if(willies==YES){

        if(popTip == nil) {

            popTip = [[[CMPopTipView alloc] initWithMessage:@"Step 1/3: This is the Action Button. You can create, view and auto-fill notes which are then added to your timeline.(Click for step 2)."] autorelease];
            popTip.delegate = self;

            [popTip presentPointingAtView:viewToPointAt inView:self.view animated:YES];
            popTip.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.8 green:0.45 blue:0.2 alpha:1];
            popTip.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        }

    }

    [viewToPointAt release];

}
```

Comment: Can you show your code where you're hiding the buttons? Are you setting them to nil?

Comment: I'm not hiding the buttons individually, I'm hiding the whole toolbar using [self.navigationController setToolBarHiden:YES]; in the views' viewWillAppear. It's super weird since another view is pushed with the exact same view appearing methods and it works normally when going back.

Comment: Not sure. I recommend posting your code.

Comment: So what is the reason for this bug @Jace ?

Comment: @Jace Facing the same issue. Got any proper solution or explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried a lot of different techniques and eventually sorted it by showing it in one view method and hiding it in the next. It's one fo the strangest bugs I have encountered and this is hardly a fix, but I hate having unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0):

You may solve this by hiding the toolbar in the next view, but that is not a very good solution, as other views that can be possibly opened from the view that contains the toolbar will all have to hide the toolbar when needed, this is annoying.

Another solution is to hide the toolbar in viewDidDisappear but there is another problem, let's say another new view needs the toolbar as well, and it sets the toolbar visible in its own viewWillAppear then the problem is that the viewWillAppear for the new view will be called actually before viewDidDisappear of the previous view, so in that case the toolbar disappear even the new view desires it.

Anyway, I'm not sure if this is a bug of iOS6 as it works fine for iOS5, what worked for me was to wrap the code that opens the new view into **dispatch_async(dispatch_queue_t queue, dispatch_block_t block)**, my understanding is that by doing this the action sheet will be dismissed before the new view is shown as you put the code that opens the new view to the end of the main queue(like what we did for viewDidDisappear, but this happens before the call to viewWillAppear of next view so it works perfect).

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution, and I think it is an Apple bug in iOS 6.0 and above.

In the `NavigationController` view stack if any view hides the toolbar, e.g. `self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = YES`, then since that point on all the Views that had already created a toolBar with buttons, will loose the buttons.

So, my solution to this problem was to keep the toolBar in all the Views(had to compromise on the UI, but in my app pikSpeak, the functionality was very important.)

Answer (score 0):

This is an ancient thread, I know, but I just recently ran into this problem.  The clue to my solution was that some delay was needed between pushing a new view and closing the action sheet.  I changed from using clickedButtonAtIndex to didDismissWithButtonIndex so that the push would occur after the action sheet was gone.  Problem solved!